# Parsing large text file and storing it in generic list - out of memory issue

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, generic-list

Following requirements:

1. Text file with approx. 250MB (around 2.5 million lines)
2. parse each line of the text-file (the structure is one line is a primary record and then there are x lines of continuation-records, then one primary record line again and x lines of continuation records, and so on)
3. if possible (and if it's avoidable), I don't want to use any databases

Why do I use all these lines in memory?
Hm good question - I´m honest, I don't want to use a database. `LINQ` is very fast and I can do all what I can do in the database, too. Further, due to the amount of different exports (after parsing the data-file) it has a positive performance effect, too. Not sure if I get the same performance with a database.

But now the issue - **it´s calling OOM (out of memory)**

Ok, here are is short code-snippet of an example class:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

class PrimaryRecord : BaseClass {
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public PrimaryRecord PRecord;
    public ContRecord CRecord;

    public PrimaryRecord() {
        CRecord = new ContRecord();    
    }
}

class ContRecord : BaseClass {
    public string CName { get; set; }
    public List<ContRecord> ContRecords { get; set; }

    public ContRecord() {
        ContRecords = new List<ContRecord>();
    }
}
```

Now, the process of parsing the text-file is as follows:

Read the file line by line and figure out, if it's a new "packages of primary + x continuation records". If yes, store the primary line into a List. All following lines (1..*) in the List, which (as you can see) is a property of the PrimaryRecord. So far so good, theoretically ...

The result is: this construct runs into an OOM and I guess it is due to the List<> and the large amount of instances of the PrimaryRecord class (and sub-instances of the ContRecord class). The memory is growing exorbitantly and I have no clue why. One word about the properties, the classes have more than one property - per class 5-10.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or in other words: does anyone have a better idea how I can parse the file and handle the structure in the memory in a more efficient way?

Comment: Maybe you can do a "Performance Analysis" in Visual Studio?

Comment: How are you parsing the file line by line, can you post some of that code?

Comment: I do this with the TextReader class and then in a loop (while) with ReadLine, line per line ... when I have read one line, I parse it and added it into the right objects/lists.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions :

- Call the constructor of List if you know how many items will be in the list (read on MSDN how memory is allocated for List)
- Try to use a LinkedList instead of a List